# Python - Predicting speeds based on text and boolean columns

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'll start by saying prediction and machine learning are totally new to me. I have spent a reasonable amount of time using python and pandas, and that's what I've started using to try and solve this problem.

I am trying to predict the speed that a fire truck will travel on a road segment (OSM data). I have millions of GPS pings from our trucks that contain their speed and I have joined this to the nearest road segment.

This has given me a dataframe like this:

```
  resource_category speed_kph highway     Paved   Urban
0 TANKERS              58     tertiary    True    True
1 TANKERS              22     residential True    True
2 TANKERS              76     primary     True    True
3 TANKERS              83     primary     True    True
4 TANKERS              83     primary     True    True
```

My question is what would be the best way to predict speed based on the *highway*, *Paved*, and *Urban* fields? If someone can point me the right direction I feel I can then work it out, but so far there are just too many options and I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an exact answer since the distribution of data and relationships between features for example will change which models are effective at accurately predicting the speed.

For starters, `sklearn` is the package you'd most likely use, but models such as Decision Tree, Logistic Regression, Linear Regression, or k-means would likely be the best, so if you can test out general models of each and see what you get then you would be in the best spot. Making accurate models right off the bat is not a common thing.

You can look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/which-machine-learning-model-to-use-db5fdf37f3dd) for more detail on the decisions of what kind of model. You will also need to improve the model and can look for more information [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-cross-validate-a-model-d6424b45261f), [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/complete-guide-to-pythons-cross-validation-with-examples-a9676b5cac12).

Whatever model you try to use, there is a lot of resources out there on how to use them, a quick google will return lots of very helpful results.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a look at those models in sklearn